# Different sized vectors according to user's input

Tags: c++, vector

```
int main() {
    int k=0;
    string s;
    cout<<"string ";
    getline(cin,s);
    float n=s.size();


     vector< vector<string> > vec(n>8?floor((sqrt(n))):3,  vector<string>(n>8?ceil((sqrt(n))):3));



    for(int i=0;n>8?i<floor((sqrt(n))):i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;n>8?j<ceil((sqrt(n))):j<3;j++)
        {
            if(k<s.size())
            {
                vec[i][j]=s[k];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }



        for(int j=0;n>8?j<ceil((sqrt(n))):j<3;j++) 
        {

    {
        for(int i=0;n>8?i<floor((sqrt(n))):i<3;i++)

            cout<<vec[i][j];

    }cout<<" ";
        }
```

I am working on an encryption program and I want to make a a vector(using it for the first time) whose size should be influenced by the user's input.How can I implement it?

Comment: Oh boy! I am not sure if encryption program is what you need to start from! Sorry!

Comment: `if (n == 6||7||8)` is very likely not doing anything remotely close to what you think it is.... Also, the variables you declare within the `if` statement are out of scope (and thus gone) immediately after the `if` statement completes...

Comment: @Grzegorz Haha,I might be getting a little ahead of myself.I am trying to arrange an input string into a matrix form with constrains[(floor(sqrt(string length)) <= width, height <= ceil(sqrt(str len)))].Everything works fine until the size of user input is 8 or 43 etc.I know there is something wrong with the logic I used.

Comment: @Ratul The change in your source made such a different impression. I retract my comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to do but you can use `rand()` function to randomize size of vectors. I wrote sample code but you should adjust it for you purpose.

```
 int maxSize1 = 10;
int maxSize2 = 15;


std::vector<string> s;
s.push_back("A");
s.push_back("B");
s.push_back("C");
s.push_back("D");



srand(time(NULL));
int size1 = rand() % maxSize1 + 1;
int size2 = rand() % maxSize2 + 1;
std::vector< std::vector<string> > vec(size1, std::vector<string>(size2));

cout << "vector sizes " << size1 << " " << size2 << endl; 

for(int i=0,k = 0;i<size1;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<size2;j++)
    {
        if(k < s.size())
        {
            vec[i][j]=s[k];
            k++;
        }

        cout << "" << vec[i][j] << ",";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Excuse me for not be lucid with my query but yes this is how I wanted to implement it.